# Multimap instead HashMap in Volley android

Tags: android, hashmap, android-volley, multimap

**What I have**

I have a `EditText` which contains `hashtags` eg : **#test #tootle #kkkk**

I have `webservice` that takes the `hashtags` from `EditText` as separate words (sentence splitted to words by `white space delimiters`)

[image]

**My problem**

I use `Volley` for my network operations , and volley takes `Hashmap` as `parameters`

```
Hashmap does not allow to have duplicate keys
```

**What I tried**

I came across `Multimap` of `guava library` , but I can't use this `Multimap` in `Volley` as well as I have other values which don't duplicates key for which I have to use `Hashmap`

**My code**

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("Title", mTittle);
for (int i = 0; i < mListAlbum.size(); i++) {
      multimap.put("AlbumName", mListAlbum.get(i));
 }
 multimap.put("uri", mUri);
mHashArray=mHashTag.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < mHashArray.length; i++) {
 multimap.put("hashtags", mHashArray[i]);
}
 multimap.put("City", mCity);
 multimap.put("Country", mCountry);
 multimap.put("Latitude", String.valueOf(mLatitude));
 multimap.put("Longitude", String.valueOf(mLongitude));     
                       networkCallImageMetaData.makeStringMultimapRequest(multimap);
```

volley

```
public void makeStringMultimapRequest(final Multimap<String, String> params) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(methodType, link, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                prgDialog.dismiss();
                try{
                    responseListenerVolley.onSuccess(new JSONObject(response));
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "makeStringRequest " + "onResponse() Exception = [" + e + "]");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                errorListenerVolley.onError(error.toString());
                prgDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return (Map<String, String>) params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Authorization", "Bearer 1DRYSS__ACn2gh1--OBtBYrQClzpbV5c5xUa9K-cPx-6YBRQOdHxU9rhk2R60cmlPcI_uCj-Y3jnNo_ENbyis1KA5ONGkYR2J0COO7H_qC_1llOEgDdcY8fAHJG05C33EqeZUlEs1JprSk22OfoBGOf89b5TuZqCGHm3NLx_3CMJnCp9lR_EXqR0QFZk03owz-Y6hCovmrMP1ihYbnbngB95U5EOPWBkgQhTB__IWCt59aEsSMxdkSY3Xi_Bt7Vc");
                return header;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with Hashmap instead of using another library for Multimap

- First Store all the hashtages in ArrayList
- Than write those Hashtags in Hashmap giving Array List index as
  Hashmap key
- if there is another data which is not hashmap you can embed key with
  index in order to differentiate them from hash tags

  ```
  List<String> mHashTags=new ArrayList<>(); //list which contains hashtags

  HashMap<String,String> mHashMap=new HashMap<>();

  for(int i=0;i<mHashTags.size();i++){
      mHashMap.put("HashTag-"+i,mHashTags.get(i));//HashTag is the tag used for hashtag u want to send other data use different tag for it 
  }
  ```

Comment: U r appending i to the key , then it changes to HashTag1,HashTag2,HashTag3 .... so on . Basically the key is changed :(.Please see my screen shot

Comment: yes key is change but it value not u can get it in php file with same sequence why u want to key the same

Comment: yes key is change but it value not u can get it in php file with same sequence why u want to key the same